# jvm class loader policy

Tags: jvm, classloader

I need to make my jvm's class loader policy as lazyloading(classes will load only when they used). How I will change jvm's class loader policy and which one is default policy Eager loading or Lazy loading?

Comment: I run some sample code and observed that by default jvm hav class loader policy as "LAZY LOADING"

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually it is up-to-optimization that default policy is Lazy loading. If you are talking about your custom class, than it will be lazy loading by default. You can implement your own class loader or to write your code in such a way that when one your custom class is loaded you will "touch" a bulk of classes that will be also loaded.

See https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21255195 for example of the optimization policy.